# Lost search function iPhone after upgrading to 4.3

Tags: iphone, search

Does anyone know how or why the search function in my text messaging is no longer working correctly after I upgraded to 4.3 on my 3G iPhone?

All was fine until I upgraded and now even tho I can see a name in a text for example I search for it and it comes back as "No results".

Comment: I too am dissapointed since the search function NEVER slowed my phone down before, and was/is the most used funtion on my phone. The upgrade to iOS 4.0 (and above), which removed the search function, has slowed it down massively, to the point where it lags on every single feature and data retrieval!

Answer (score 6):

Searching SMS messages was disabled due to battery life and performance concerns for the 3G, you can see this in the iPhone: Which iOS 4 software features does my iPhone support? article on apple.com

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4204

> iPhone 3G does not support Spotlight search for SMS/MMS messages.

Comment: how is this answer useful? sorry but anybody knows how to fix this problem? I too cant search for text in my messages or emails. use to be the most effective function i used. it only brings up the messages after the upgrade evn though the messages are still in the same folder. There must be a fix to allow search for all contents (not just the contecnts after the upgrade)
please help!
s

Comment: Nope. This is the correct answer. You are asking to do something that is no longer possible. It is like being annoyed that you asked the question "How do I fly by flapping my arms?" and someone says "It doesn't work like that." If you downgrade your device you can probably return search functionality, but it was disabled in 4.0 because it caused unacceptable slowdown in devices.